# Google maps won't load in angular project because of Error: No provider for MapsAPILoader?

Tags: angular, google-maps

I have an angular project and I am trying to get the google maps module  ([Googlemaps library](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps)) working. I have used this library before and not had this issue. But for some reason I am having this issue now. One difference between this situation and previous usecases is this time I am lazy loading the module, that uses the google maps. Although the admin.module file imports the google maps module in the same way that I have done when I have gotten it work. I have tried to provide MapsApiLoader in admin.module. But this does not work because a typescript error is thrown. This is what my typescript error looks like, the error in the console when running the app, and package.json look like . Because I have had this working in another app. I feel like it is a dependency issue. But any suggestions as to why this error is thrown in the console would be helpful. Thanks!

I have edited this to include admin.module.ts and app.module.ts. admin.module.ts is imported in app.module.ts and lazy loaded in app-routing.module.ts

[image]

[image]

```
{
  "name": "admin-guest",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.26.20",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-facebook-sdk": "^2.1.1",
    "angular2-google-maps": "^0.16.0",
    "ng2-img-cropper": "^0.9.0",
    "ngx-facebook": "^2.4.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.87",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

App.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SplashComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MdMenuModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MdCardModule,
    GuestModule,
    AdminModule,
    MdIconModule

  ],
  providers: [
    AuthguardService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

admin.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AdminComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DisplayRecommendationsComponent,
    DisplayEventsComponent,
    GuestHomepageComponent,
    MovieDialog,
    SettingsComponent,
    CreateComponent,
    WelcomeComponent,
    GoogleMapComponent,
    GoogleuxComponent,
    CreateEventComponent,
    CreateRecommendationComponent,
    UsernameComponent,
    PasswordComponent,
    EmailComponent,
    ImageComponent,
    InstagramComponent,
    LocationComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    AboutmeComponent,
    InstagramHelp,
    SignupComponent,
    TermsDialog,
    PasswordReset,
    ChangePasswordComponent,
    HelpComponent,
    EditRecommendationComponent,
    FbComponent,
    ImageCropperUploaderComponent,
    ChangeEmployeeImage,
    MultipleImageCropperComponent,
    SignupImageCropperComponent,
    NofacebookloginComponent,
    AddSettingsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MdMenuModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    MdCardModule,
    MdGridListModule,
    MdIconModule,
    MdInputModule,
    MdInputModule,
    MdDialogModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MdNativeDateModule,
    MdDatepickerModule,
    MdToolbarModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MdTooltipModule,
    FacebookModule.forRoot(),
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot(
      {
        apiKey:'***',
        libraries: ["places"]
      }
    ),
    ImageCropperModule
  ],
  providers: [
    EmployeeHttpService,
    EmployeeService,
    UserLoaded,
    MoreInfo,
    DeserializationService,
    NewImageService,
    HttpService,
    SplashHttp,
    FacebookService,
    ApiKeyService,
    ContentService,
    AuthguardService,
    ImagePathService,
    AWSuploadService,
    EmployeeErrorService,
    LocationService,
    LoginService,
    ResponseService
  ],
  entryComponents:[
    MovieDialog,
    InstagramHelp,
    TermsDialog,
    PasswordReset,
    HelpComponent,
    EditRecommendationComponent,
    ImageCropperUploaderComponent,
    ChangeEmployeeImage,
    MultipleImageCropperComponent,
    SignupImageCropperComponent
  ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

Comment: post your app.module.ts please

Comment: I don't see the 'imports' part

Comment: Do you check if /node_modules/angular2-google-maps exist ? A little obvious but can happen

Comment: @Vega I took away the imports to spare the readers of clutter the angular2-Google-maps does exist.

Comment: I saw in the docs that the package has a new name, so do you have the folder of that? (old) name

Comment: Thanks that did the trick I upgraded to the @agm/core version, and now it works.

Comment: Great! you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing below code in imports for the module that is using google maps API.

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
 apiKey: '',
}),
```